# Why do phasers skip from Type X to Type XII?

Tags: star-trek, phaser

After Type X phasers were equipped on the Galaxy class and other ships of the era, the next most powerful phasers were Type XII phasers, usually equipped on starbases or heavily fortified stations. The first ship class to use these phasers was the Sovereign class. But why didn't they use Type XI phasers? Where were they if they were used?

Comment: Why did US fighters go from the F-18 to the F-22 to the F-35 with no production models in between?

Comment: Quick google suggests there are F19 to 21s (admittedly the F19s is a rumoured and not confirmed secret plane, giving it a sequential number was a bit silly if they wanted to keep it secret)

Comment: There was also a YF-23...

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - which lost the competition to the YF-22, so the F-22 went into production rather than the F-23...

Comment: Maybe for the same reason Windows went directly from 8 to 10? W8 was hated so much that Microsoft wanted to signal a big leap forward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Memory Beta, taking the DS9 technical manual as their source, Type XI phasers were in fact used, and were installed on Deep Space 9.

> A Type-XI phaser was a type of phaser emitter usually installed on Federation Starfleet space stations.

> History
> When Starfleet began upgrading Deep Space 9's defenses in preparation of a Dominion assault in the early 2370s, arrays of this type were installed in the station's defense sails, along with Type-IX phaser turrets. (DS9 reference: Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual)

https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Type-XI_phaser